# Javascript in C# WebBrowser Control not executed when designmode activated

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

**solution:**

Javascript is not executed inside a webbrowser-control when designmode is set to "on", in my case it was:

```
document = webbrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;
document.designMode = "On";
```

the designmode property stopped the webbrowser-control executing javascript, so i changed it to the following:

```
document.body.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
```

now the javascripts are executed and editing the document ist still possible, so this simple change solved the problem for me. thanks for all replies

**original question:**

i am trying to implement a C# GUI with a WebBrowser-control. Within the Webbrowser i am calling local stored HTML-Files, the files are always stored on C: or D:, they are not on shared folders or something like that.
Everything works fine so far.

Now i tried to add some JavaScript to the HTML-Files with some basic functions to edit html-tables (Add Row, Add Column etc). But the Javascript is not executed inside the webbrowser-control. I tried to open the files with IE and i get prompted for ActiveX contents, i tell IE "Allow blocked content" and everything works fine. (I dont get the prompt inside the webbrowser-control.)
Now the Question: Is it possible to "always enable" any kind of scripting in a webbrowser-control or to prompt in the same way like IE does ?

Of course i searched the Web and Stackoverflow and i found several Solutions:

1. IE only prompts for local files. Javascript from any website (e.g. http://javatester.org/javascript.html) is executed. Adding the following Code to the local HTML-File should fix this problem (as mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx). I tried it with the very basic example from the msdn site and it worked, but after adding some more Code it didnt work anymore. IE prompted me again, so this solution seemed not be reliable to me.

   `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->`

   or

   `<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.contoso.com/ -->`
2. Another solution was to change the security settings of IE, this should also affect the webbrowser-control. So i tried set all zones to the lowest security level (Internet options -> security), after that i clicked "custom level" to enable even more. But it still didnt work, i still got prompted. There was only one thing i did not understand: Open HTML-Files in the normal-mode prompted me for executing script, but the inprivate-mode immediatelly executed any script. Is this just a bug or normal behaviour? But finally changing security settings again brought no solution
3. The Invokescript Method inside my C# Programm could not run any scripts again.
4. Edit Tables directly (with `execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", true);`) doesnt work since this command is not supported by the IE.

So if you read until this point, i have to say thank you. And if you got any idea, how to reliable activate JavaScripts inside the webbrowser-control or just how to edit html-tables inside a webbrowser-control, i would be really happy :)

Btw: I am using .NET 4.5 and i tested all the solutions and two different PCs with different users. Finally i am sorry for my english, hope everyone could understand.

edit: Basic example, which works fine in IE (not even prompting) but its not executing any kind of JS in webbrowser-control:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.contoso.com/ -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Mark of the Web Example test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>Hello, World</p>
     <script language="JavaScript">
        document.write ("Hello Javascript");
    </script>

    <p>
    alert test
    </p>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        alert("test");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Sure, i have added a very simple example (based on the ms example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Is your application [tag:wpf] or [tag:winforms]?

Comment: I tried your html/javascript code in a [tag:winforms] application. And i get the alert as well as the page content.

Comment: it works without this `<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.contoso.com/ -->` line also

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: hah damn you are right, it's a WPF application and it works - as long as designmode ist turned off. In my application i turned on designmode to edit the contents of the HTML-Files. Seems like designmode will not execute any script. i will try to solve it and update the question then. Thanks so far.

Comment: ok finally i got the solution:
`document.designmode="On"` does not execute any javascript, so i changed it to:
`document.body.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");`

thanks for your replies, was testing for a few days without any idea :)

Comment: why don't you post your answer?

Comment: added answer ;)
(i didnt find the button, i am not able to do anything on monday morning -.-)

Comment: This is an old question so it is not work spending time on it but usually when a question says something like "not executed" it helps to get details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is not executed inside a webbrowser-control when designmode is set to "on", in my case it was:

```
document = webbrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;
document.designMode = "On";
```

the designmode property stopped the webbrowser-control executing javascript, so i changed it to the following:

```
document.body.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
```

now the javascripts are executed and editing the document ist still possible, so this simple change solved the problem for me. thanks for all replies